# Pointer address shifts slightly during function call

Tags: c++, pointers

My `char*` parameter seems to be changing address without my directly modifying it. I print the address of the `char*` both in a `custom deallocator` and then immediately after in another function. I do not explicitly perform any changes on the `char*` but the address is always slightly different in the two logged statements.

Here's my custom deallocator in relevant part:

```
    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t MAX_SIZE, int ID, template <class Created> class MemPolicy>
    void arena<N, MAX_SIZE, ID, MemPolicy>::deallocate(char* p, std::size_t n) 
    {
      std::cout << "inside arena deallocate p is " << &p << std::endl;
      std::cout << "inside arena deallocate n is " << n << std::endl;
      MemPolicy<char>::addMemory(p, n);
...
}
```

Here's void addMemory:

```
void addMemory(char* p, std::size_t n){
      std::cout << "adding memory: " << &p << std::endl;
      std::cout << "size is: " << n << std::endl;
    }
```

When I print out the parameters, the sizes are identical, but the pointers are  slightly different. This is what I see, quite consistently (not the exact numbers, but similarly different each time):

```
//I expect these numbers to match exactly, but clearly they don't
inside arena deallocate p is 0x7ffc2dff8210 //inside deallocator
adding memory: 0x7ffc2dff81e0  //inside addMemory()
```

The difference between the values is usually varies between 50 and 200 (in decimal).

Here's what I've tried:

- declaring addMemory to take `const char*` instead of `char*`. This did not make a difference.
- printing the address out twice in the deallocator. In that case the address is always the same. So it's not the printing that is shifting the pointer (and why should it?)
- commenting out everything in my deallocator after the addMemory() call to make sure there isn't something else in the deallocating function affecting p. This also made no difference.

I have not coded with thread safety in mind, so I am wondering whether the deallocator is being called in a threaded manner due to STL implementation details (my deallocator is used with a `std::vector`). Is that a possibility for why p is moving around? What else should I be checking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two variables named `p`, one in `deallocate()` and one in `addMemory()`. While they might point to the same memory location, they are two different variables, so they have different addresses.

In order to print the actual pointer value instead of the pointer addresses, do this:

```
std::cout << "adding memory: " << (void*) p << std::endl;
```

instead of this:

```
std::cout << "adding memory: " << &p << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the **address** of your pointer is changing, (because you're printing the address of *different* variables named `p`), but the **value** of your pointer (which is an address) is not changing.

A `char *`, while it is a pointer, is *itself* being passed by value to your functions.

You're printing `&p` which is the address of *the pointer*, and not its value. The reason you're seeing it "move around" is because you're printing the address of a *different* local variable (also named `p`) in the stack frame of different functions.

If you print `(void*)p`, you'll see its value (which is an address) stay the same.

Comment: I am new to C++ and sometimes doubt my syntax. I did start with printing p, as that seemed the most logical, but for me that actually doesn't print anything but a blank space. Perhaps it depends on the compiler?

Comment: @sunny `char *` is treated specially by the I/O stream objects; since it's often used in C as the string type, the `char *` overload of `ostream::operator>>` tries to print it as a C string. Cast it explicitly to `void *` before printing it, and you will see the address.

Answer (score 1):

The `p` inside the `addMemory` function is a different `p` to the one in `deallocate` - they have different addresses even though they both point to the same address.